# Trying to get kube-stats-metrics to run in kubernetes cluster v 1.10.11

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubectl

Good day.

I am currently trying to get `kube-stats-metrics` up and running based on https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics#setup.
I manages until the part where i have the add the role binding. My shell says it succeded, but if i now run `kubectl apply -f kubernetes` i get the following error

```
Error from server (Forbidden): error when creating "kubernetes/kube-state-metrics-cluster-role.yaml": clusterroles.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "kube-state-metrics" is forbidden: attempt to grant extra privileges: [PolicyRule{APIGroups:[""], Resou
rces:["configmaps"], Verbs:["list"]} PolicyRule{APIGroups:[""], Resources:["configmaps"], Verbs:["watch"]} PolicyRule{APIGroups:[""], Resources:["secrets"], Verbs:["list"]} PolicyRule{APIGroups:[""], Resources:["secrets"], Verbs:["watch"]} Poli
cyRule{APIGroups:[""], Resources:["nodes"], Verbs:["list"]} PolicyRule{APIGroups:[""], Resources:["nodes"], Verbs:["watch"]} PolicyRule{APIGroups:[""], Resources:["pods"], Verbs:["list"]} PolicyRule{APIGroups:[""], Resources:["pods"], Verbs:["w
atch"]} PolicyRule{APIGroups:[""], Resources:["services"], Verbs:["list"]} PolicyRule{APIGroups:[""], Resources:["services"], Verbs:["watch"]} PolicyRule{APIGroups:[""], Resources:["resourcequotas"], Verbs:["list"]} PolicyRule{APIGroups:[""], R
esources:["resourcequotas"], Verbs:["watch"]} PolicyRule{APIGroups:[""], Resources:["replicationcontrollers"], Verbs:["list"]} PolicyRule{APIGroups:[""], Resources:["replicationcontrollers"], Verbs:["watch"]} PolicyRule{APIGroups:[""], Resource
s:["limitranges"], Verbs:["list"]} PolicyRule{APIGroups:[""], Resources:["limitranges"], Verbs:["watch"]} PolicyRule{APIGroups:[""], Resources:["persistentvolumeclaims"], Verbs:["list"]} PolicyRule{APIGroups:[""], Resources:["persistentvolumecl
aims"], Verbs:["watch"]} PolicyRule{APIGroups:[""], Resources:["persistentvolumes"], Verbs:["list"]} PolicyRule{APIGroups:[""], Resources:["persistentvolumes"], Verbs:["watch"]} PolicyRule{APIGroups:[""], Resources:["namespaces"], Verbs:["list"
]} PolicyRule{APIGroups:[""], Resources:["namespaces"], Verbs:["watch"]} PolicyRule{APIGroups:[""], Resources:["endpoints"], Verbs:["list"]} PolicyRule{APIGroups:[""], Resources:["endpoints"], Verbs:["watch"]} PolicyRule{APIGroups:["extensions"
```

Anyone has encountered this?

Comment: Seems that Kube API server admission and validation checking rejected applying of provided resources. Can you share the output of this command?
`kubectl create clusterrolebinding cluster-admin-binding --clusterrole=cluster-admin --user=$(gcloud info --format='value(config.account)')`

Comment: Finally, you have tried the command that Adrian suggest you?